# Access to req object in success callback

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-twitter

I need to get access to `req` object in success callback of Twitter Passport:

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    //here I need `req` object
  }
));
```

How can I access to that in success callback scope?

Comment: What `req` object? What is the scope of it? (As you don't have it in the code you provided)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer. You need to set `passReqToCallback: true` in options, then the first parameter of callback will be `req` object:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/39